# hook_node_grants() implemented by a custom module is not invoked

Tags: hooks, users

I am using the following code in a Drupal 7 module.

```
define('BNA_ACCESS_REALM', 'billetsalget_nodeaccess');

function billetsalget_nodeaccess_node_access_records($node) {
  $producttypes = array('internal_product', 'external_product', 'call_product', 'event_product');
  $grants = array();

  if (in_array($node->type, $producttypes)) {
    $grants[] = array(
      'realm' => BNA_ACCESS_REALM,
      'gid' => $node->nid,
      'grant_view' => TRUE,
      'grant_update' => 0,
      'grant_delete' => 0,
      'priority' => 0,
    );
  }

  return !empty($grants) ? $grants : array();
}

function billetsalget_nodeaccess_node_grants($account, $op) {
  dpm($account);
  die(var_dump($account));
}
```

`hook_node_access_records()` is working and running as it should, adding data to the database.
As far as I can see `hook_node_grants()` is never invoked. I have tried with all sorts of stuff in there, but it just looks like it doesn't even run.

---

It didn't have anything to do with my code. I'm new to Drupal so I didn't know `hook_node_grants()` don't get invoked when I'm signed in as an administrator.
Newbie mistake from my side :)

Comment: `hook_node_grants()` is invoked from these functions: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/invokes/hook_node_grants/7 if that helps

Comment: @Clive Especially part *"node_access_rebuild in modules/node/node.module Rebuilds the node access database."* - rebuilding should trigger it all right. Grants is not called on each access due to performance problems. martindilling have you tried to rebuild that database?

Comment: Well... This is embarrassing xD This is my first project in Drupal so I didn't know that function don't run when signed in as an administrator -.-'  
So frustrating figuring that out after 2 days with that problem xD

Answer (score 2):

It didn't have anything to do with my code. I'm new to Drupal so I didn't know **hook_node_grants() don't get invoked when I'm signed in as an administrator**. Newbie mistake from my side :)

Comment: Ah yes - User 1 bypasses all checks that go though `user_access()` (it's hard-coded) so that explains it

Comment: Yea, really really annoying to find out that was the problem after 2 days :P but now it works as intended :D

Comment: It's a mistake you only ever make once ;)